# ¿Cómo saber si un jButton se está presionando?

Tags: java, java-swing, jbutton

Tengo un botón al cual me gustaría darle cierto color cuando lo estoy presionando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy creando esta interfaz con Netbeans

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y veo que se le pueden asignar diferentes eventos, pero no sé exactamente dónde puedo leer la documentación de estos porque busco en Oracle y no encuentro información acerca de estos otros

Comment: [Está explicado aquí con ejemplos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#abstractbutton). Se trata de implementar `Action Listener`, [aquí tienes la documentación al respecto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

Comment: solo cuando lo presiones o cuando lo mantengas presionado?? por que puedes usar el focus para cuando se presione.